# Find the name of package containing a file, given the file's path

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to find the package a file is in with a shell command. Background is, I want to use "rospack cflags-only-I " to get a list of directories to look for c++ headers to build ctags for omnicompletion. See [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/527/vim-code-completion-under-ros).
Currently I need to set the pwd of the editor to the package dir. Would be nice to get rid of that limitation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9594/find-the-name-of-package-containing-a-file,-given-the-file%27s-path/) by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6468 on 2011-03-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know any ros command, but the following script works.
It's quite slow though using rospack list and just checking prefixes (so half filenames will work too).

```
#!/bin/bash
pkg_file=$1

for i in $(rospack list | awk '{print $2}'); do
   pkg_name=$(basename $i)
   if [[ ${pkg_file} == ${i}* ]]; then
      echo ${pkg_name}
      exit 0
   fi
done
```

Searching for manifest.xml:

```
#!/bin/bash
pkg_file=$1
pkg_dir=$(dirname ${pkg_file})

pushd . > /dev/null

cd ${pkg_dir}

while [[ ! -e manifest.xml ]]; do
   cd ..
   if [[ $(pwd) == "/" ]]; then
      break
   fi
done

if [[ -e manifest.xml ]]; then
   echo $(basename `pwd`)
fi

popd > /dev/null
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-29**:
A directory is a package if it contains a manifest.xml file.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-03-29**:
I'm not sure what makes a directory a package, but alternately you could just cd to the file's directory and then do 'cd .." until there is a manifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The get_pkg_dir in roslib.packages is a way to do it in python http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roslib/html/python/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1